# Recommended way to versionize single-file-scripts using git?

Tags: git, powershell

We got many single-file scripts that don't belong to a specific project/product/component. Should we create a repository for ach of this single-file scripts? Is there some other technic I am not aware off?

What is the recommended way to versionize them using git?

**Approach A:** One repo called e.g. "hodgepodge" containing all files (fileA.ps1, fileB.ps1, ...)

**Approach B:** One repo for each file, e.g. fileA (holding fileA.ps1), fileB (Holding fileB.ps1) and so on...

Comment: Do some of those scripts call other scripts?

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Approach C: One branch for each file in one repo.

Comment: If they reside within the same directory (from what I know) it's going to be hard to have an individual repo for each of them. Otherwise it depends on what kind of information you would like to record. If you just need to record that something change a single branch might be fine. If you wan to track the individual progression a branch for each file would be an option.

Comment: I have a folder in my `home` which contains a bunch of single-file-scripts. As they are imported all at the same time, I personally prefer to versionize them as one repo. If they would be distributet over the file system, I'd use one repo for each file (gist is good for that)

Comment: Why do you want to use git for this? rcs still works well, same as ever.

Comment: @ElpieKay "Approach C: One branch for each file in one repo. – " Can you do that remotely?

Comment: @Erwann What do you mean by "remotely" here? If you mean not cloning the repository and creating a branch that tracks one file in the remote repository, it depends on the hosting service. Some support online edit, and some also provide http/https apis.

Comment: @ElpieKay "and creating a branch that tracks one file in the remote repository, it depends on the hosting service" How does one do that within github.com, if applicable?